# how to add/activate print function on qgis cloud and set the extent to a specific layer?

Tags: cloud, gis, qgis

1.My print function is not active on my qgiscloud whilst  in others its active like this one https://qgiscloud.com/anitagraser/corine_austria

Can someone please assist me

2. Is it possible to set the extent in qgis cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have created a layout with composer in the QGIS project you published. ONce you do so, the print option will be enabled. My question is why my scale options for printing top out at 1:50,000?

You can limit the scales at which your cloud map can be viewed. Log in to your qgiscloud account, click on Maps, click on the edit icon, and scroll down to where you can put in a list of scales, separated by commas. to test this, I put in 5000, 20000, 200000 and indeed it limited the user to ONLY those scales, which doesn't exactly limit the extent but sort of does.